# Model for doubly nested subjects in lme4 R package

Tags: r, lm, lme4, multi-level

In my data.frame (`dat`), I have the following variables:

`st.id`: id of students

`sc.id`: id of 4 schools that students are in (`W/X/Y/Z`)

`group`: determines two schools are Treatment and the other two are Control (`C/T`)

`gender`: of students (`M/F`)

`time`: number of times each student tested (`1/ 2/ 3`)

`y`: Continuous outcome variable

Using `lme4` or another appropriate R package, I wonder how to write the model to measure the effect of the `group` in this design given nestedness of students (`st.id`) within `time` and within schools (`sc.id`)?

Here is my current model code but I'm not sure how to include `time` in the random part below?

```
lme4::lmer(y ~ group * gender * time + (time |sc.id/st.id), data = dat)
```